# Sending SMS programatically from Asp.net in different Indian languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

I would like to know the C# code or webservice to send SMS in English as well as in different Indian languages such as Hindi, Tamil, etc. I have used mVaayoo to send SMS in English from my application.

I would also like to know how to input the Indian language through my web form. Please suggest any site/gateway that provides the API/webservice for use in sending multi-language SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below link.
You have to open an account on the free sms sending website as mentioned in the post.

http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2012/04/sending-sms-via-c-using-way2sms-160by2.html

download the dll that they provide. Include the dll in your code(add reference).

Comment: The site does not state sending message in other human languages. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @NishaS : you need to hardcore the message in the language you want.

Comment: How do I hardcode the message in c# language? I am sending my message from codebehind. Is there a way to use unicode in c# to obtain the desired output?

Comment: do you have a fixed message to send.? or if it is dynamic then data type pf the message field in database should be nvarchar